# Why doesn't Tkinter show my stopwatch incrementing?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, while-loop, timer

I have successfully made a function that outputs (as print() ) the stopwatch time from 0 to 5 seconds.

I want to use Tkinter to show the stopwatch output in an entry window when you click a button 'start'. For some reason, when you click start, it just loads for 5 seconds, then only displays the last output (5.0 sec).

Why doesn't it show the output dynamically changing from 0.0 - 5.0 sec? I'm enclosing the code here - I cannot figure out why this isn't working...

```
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()  # creating a window instance
win.title('stopwach')

def start_timer():
    """begin timer from 1-5"""
    start_time = time.time()
    stopwatch=0 # initializing
    while stopwatch <= 5:
        current_time = time.time()
        stopwatch = current_time - start_time
        entry_field.delete(0, END)
        entry_field.insert(0, str(format(stopwatch, ".1f")) + " sec")
        time.sleep(0.01)
    

entry_field = Entry(win, width=35, borderwidth=5)
entry_field.pack()

message_1 = Label(win, text='5 second stopwatch')
message_1.pack()

button_1 = Button(win, text='START', command=start_timer)
button_1.pack()


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: can't use loops in the same thread as tkinter, they block the main loop, You can however use either `.update()` method (not suggested) or `.after()` loops or another thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `time.sleep` with tkinter, as it blocks the GUI until it finishes. For tkinter, you should use `root.after`, like this:

```py
def start_timer():
    """begin timer from 1-5"""
    global start_time, stopwatch
    start_time = time.time()
    stopwatch=0 # initializing
    tick_timer()

def tick_timer():
    global start_time, stopwatch
    if stopwatch <= 5:
        current_time = time.time()
        stopwatch = current_time - start_time
        entry_field.delete(0, END)
        entry_field.insert(0, "%.1f" % stopwatch + " sec")
        win.after(100, tick_timer) #Wait 100ms then run again
```

This splits the timer into two functions. `start_timer` initialises the variables and then calls `tick_timer`. This does the same thing as before, but at the end I used `win.after` instead of `time.sleep` to call the `tick_timer` function again after 100ms. This then works as expected.